# Adding property to function with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.2

Say I have a function expression called run:

```
let run = function(){


};
```

I want to add a property called "default" to this run function, a reference to itself.

```
run.default = run;
```

this is to support multiple module export formats in JS.

I hear the best way to do this is with a namespace.

Here is my actual code:

```
namespace run {

  export interface Run {
    (paths: Array<string>, opts: run.IOpts, cb: Function): void
    default: Run;
  }

  export interface IOpts {
    babelExec?: string,
    all?: boolean
  }
}


  const run : run.Run = function (paths: Array<string>, opts: run.IOpts, cb: Function): void {

    //....

  }


run.default = run;
export = run;
```

but I get this warning:

[image]

Does anyone know why that error message occurs?

As you can see, TS thinks I don't have the property typings for the default property, but I am pretty sure I do with the namespace declaration...or not? So confused by this error - the error/warning seems incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is effected because the function you are assigning to `default` does not have a `default` property - it's just a function.

You've declared `default` as `Run`, so anything assigned to it will also have to have a `default` property.

You could either make `default` optional:

```
default?: Run;
```

Or could declare it as a function:

```
default: (paths: Array<string>, opts: run.IOpts, cb: Function) => void;
```

Comment: hmm, thanks, but the default property in my code should point to the run function which has a default property, which points to a run function which has the default property. It's just a circular reference, not sure what's wrong with what I have but maybe this solution will work, thanks!

Comment: I think what you are saying is that the default property is not attached to the run function until after declaration...that must be the problem. This solution seems to work, thanks.

Comment: Yep, you've got it.

Answer (score 1):

If you weren't using a reserved word (`default`) you could do it like:

```
export function run() {
  // ...
}

export namespace run {
  export const DEFAULT = run;
}
```

But for what you seemed to be trying to do I think the simplest would be:

```
export function run() {
  // ...
}

export default run;
```